# <f:facet> not working with <h:form>

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2

I have a template, in which a `<h:form>` is defined. This `<h:form>` is used all over the application for the CRUD pages of entities.

So, at one place I need another `enctype` for the form, so that I can upload files. I thought I can solve this with a facet in the template:

```
<h:form id="main-form">
    <f:facet name="enctype">
        <ui:insert name="form-enctype"/>
    </f:facet>

    <ui:insert name="buttons"/><p/>
    <ui:insert name="content"/><p/>
    <ui:insert name="buttons"/>
    <ui:insert name="additionalHelper"/>

</h:form>
```

And at the concrete page I wanted to set the custom `enctype` this way:

```
<ui:define name="form-enctype">
    <h:outputText value="multipart/form-data"/>
</ui:define>
```

But in the source code I always end up with the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`as `enctype` for the `<h:form>`

Why is this happening? At other locations in the source code this is behaving properly.

Comment: Only elements that are specified to have facets have facets. You can't just make it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference pages for [h:form](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/form.html) does not mention `enctype` facet. I don't think it is valid facet for `h:form`. However, there is attribute `enctype`.

If you want to define content type of the form in specific pages then use template parameters like shown below.

Template would look then:

```
<h:form id="main-form" enctype="#{myenctype}">

    <ui:insert name="buttons"/><p/>
    <ui:insert name="content"/><p/>
    <ui:insert name="buttons"/>
    <ui:insert name="additionalHelper"/>

</h:form>
```

and specific page has to define `<ui:param name="myenctype" value="multipart/form-data"/>`:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="myenctype" value="multipart/form-data"/>
    <!-- other stuff like <ui:define ...> -->
</ui:composition>
```

If you want to provide default value for the parameter use ternary operator like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469750/facelets-uiparam-default-value).