# JSF <f:facet> contents not rendered

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facet

I have a page where I need to nest some components inside a `<f:facet name="last>`, in order to apply custom styles (I'm using Primefaces and this is their their way of handling CSS priority ordering as mentioned [here](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433)). But I'm not able to render anything placed inside the `<f:facet>` tags.

Here's some sample code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="loginField" value="Login:" styleClass="form-label"/>
            <p:inputText id="loginField" value="#{subscriptionBean.login}" styleClass="form-field"/>
            <f:facet name="last">
                <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password:" styleClass="form-label"/>
                <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{subscriptionBean.password}" required="true" match="pwd1" styleClass="form-field"/>
                <p:message for="pwd2" display="text" styleClass="form-field"/>
            </f:facet>
        </h:form>
    </div>        
</h:body>
```

Shouldn't I be able to see the password input field in the generated page? It simply doesn't show up.

Following starf's answer here's some sample code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css"/>
    </f:facet>
</h:head>

<h:body>
        <h:outputText value="Rendered text!"/>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="pdw1" value="Password: "/>
            <p:password id="pwd1" required="true"/>
            <p:message for="pwd1"/>
        </h:form>

</h:body>
```

And the resulting rendered page header:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/AquitelManagement/faces/javax.faces.resource/default.css?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/AquitelManagement/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0.RC2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/AquitelManagement/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0.RC2">    
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/AquitelManagement/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0.RC2">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/AquitelManagement/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0.RC2">
</script>
</head>
<body>...
```

Comment: So, your question is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css?

Comment: I'm sorry @BalusC but I wouldn't classify as a duplicate. I was trying to understand why the solution proposed in primeface's blog wasn't working. Although the workarounds proposed there also solve my problem, they don't answer my question. The explanation given in primeface's forum, linked by starf, did.

Comment: You've just a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You faced a problem with overriding PrimeFaces CSS. Instead of asking how to achieve that, you tried something completely wrong and concretely asked why that didn't work without elaborating anything about the initial problem of overriding the PrimeFaces CSS for which you incorrectly thought that the given code was the right solution to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to register a facet on the h:form tag. The example in the link is registered on the h:head tag. Primefaces has a custom renderer for head.

There is no such facet defined for form, so it doesn't know how to handle it. See also [<f:facet> not working with <h:form>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937757/ffacet-not-working-with-hform)

I believe you are confusing the css ordering issue. If you wish to override the PrimeFaces css, use the "last" facet in the head - which would place your css definition below the primefaces css.

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/style.css" />
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

See http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/ for a good explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do believe you're right, and I did as sugested, and linked my css inside a `<f:facet name="last">` inside the `<h:head>` tag. It does render the relative link to my css, but it does so before the link to Primefaces css file, I'd like it to be the other way so I could use my css, what did I do wrong? Gonna edit the main post with the results.

Comment: @BrunoPires It seems this has been covered in the Primefaces forums - http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25617. Try with the <link> tag directly, although this isn't ideal.

Comment: Or place your h:outputStylesheet tags in the body itself.